# Logstash - JDBC - MYSQL config error

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, logstash

After watching this tutorial ;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnI_rlrei1s

I'm trying to fetch my localhost mysql (using laravel valet mysql) using logstash with jdbc to sent to elasticsearch server .

This is my config :

```
# file: db.conf
input {
jdbc {
    # MySQL jdbc connection string to our database, mydb
    jdb_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dragon"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as 
    jdbc_user => "root"
    # The user password
    jdbc_password => ""
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "/Users/muaz/downloads/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
    # The name of the deliver clas for MySQL
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    # Our query
    statement = "SELECT * from Receipt"
}
}
output {
# stdout { codec => json_lines }
elasticsearch {
    # protocol = https
    index => "power_receipt"
    document_type => "Receipt"
    document_id => "%{id}"
    host => "https://search-power-yidhfhkidiiddcccyhyrijaagamu.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com"
}
}
```

And i run it using command (in logstash folder) :

```
./bin/logstash agent -f db.conf
```

It produce :

```
fetched an invalid config {:config=>"# file: db.conf\ninput {\n\tjdbc {\n\t\t# MySQL jdbc connection string to our database, mydb\n\t\tjdb_connection_string => \"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dragon\"\n\t\t# The user we wish to execute our statement as \n\t\tjdbc_user => \"root\"\n\t\t# The user password\n\t\tjdbc_password => \"\"\n\t\t# The path to our downloaded jdbc driver\n\t\tjdbc_driver_library => \"/Users/muaz/downloads/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar\"\n\t\t# The name of the deliver clas for MySQL\n\t\tjdbc_driver_class => \"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\"\n\t\t# Our query\n\t\tstatement = \"SELECT * from Receipt\"\n\t}\n}\noutput {\n\t# stdout { codec => json_lines }\n\telasticsearch {\n\t\t# protocol = https\n\t\tindex => \"slurp_receipt\"\n\t\tdocument_type => \"Receipt\"\n\t\tdocument_id => \"%{id}\"\n\t\thost => \"https://search-power-yidhfhkidiiddcccyhyrijaagamu.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com\"\n\t}\n}\n\n\n", :reason=>"Expected one of #, => at line 15, column 13 (byte 521) after # file: db.conf\ninput {\n\tjdbc {\n\t\t# MySQL jdbc connection string to our database, mydb\n\t\tjdb_connection_string => \"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dragon\"\n\t\t# The user we wish to execute our statement as \n\t\tjdbc_user => \"root\"\n\t\t# The user password\n\t\tjdbc_password => \"\"\n\t\t# The path to our downloaded jdbc driver\n\t\tjdbc_driver_library => \"/Users/muaz/downloads/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar\"\n\t\t# The name of the deliver clas for MySQL\n\t\tjdbc_driver_class => \"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\"\n\t\t# Our query\n\t\tstatement ", :level=>:error}
```

How to solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on the last line of your `jdbc` input

```
statement = "SELECT * from Receipt"
```

should read

```
statement => "SELECT * from Receipt"
```

Also in your `elasticsearch` output you need to change

```
host => "https://search-power-yidhfhkidiiddcccyhyrijaagamu.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com"
```

to

```
hosts => ["https://search-power-yidhfhkidiiddcccyhyrijaagamu.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
```

Comment: it fix , but i got new error :

INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://search-power-yidhfhkidiiddcccyhyrijaagamu.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com:989: Connection reset
Aug 22, 2016 5:07:42 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

Comment: I got new error : search-power-yidhfhkidiiddcccyhyrijaagamu.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com:989 failed to respond {:class=>"Manticore::ClientProtocolException", :level=>:error}

Comment: error above has been fix , and now new problem : Tue Aug 23 12:13:37 MYT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'.